# Kien meti prepozicion en frazo kun "unu la alia"?

Tags: prepositions

Kie tauĝas la prepozicio kiam "unu la alia" estas nerekta objekto de frazo?

Ekzemple, kiu el ĉi tiuj frazoj estas ĝusta?

1. Ili sendis donacojn unu al la alia.
2. Ili sendis donacojn al unu la alia.

Answer (score 2):

La prepozicio estas metata antaŭ tiun parton, kie ĝi havas sencon, ĉar "unu la alia" ja estas du sendependaj partoj kaj ne - kiel en kelkaj lingvoj, ekz. la germana - unu vortformo.

La ĝusta esprimo do estas *Ili sendis donacojn unu al la alia.*

*unu* plipreczigas la subjekton kaj kune kun *la alia* montras, ke temas pri reciprokeco. Oni povus tiun frazon esprimi ankaŭ per *Unu sendis donacojn al la alia.* Kp. ankaŭ [ĉi tiun respondon](http://akademio.info/akademio/index.php?title=Respondoj_de_la_Lingva_Konsultejo_(parto_11)#Kompleksa_esprimo_de_reciprokeco) de la Lingvo Konsultejo de la Akademio de Esperanto pri simila strukturo.